# Combination of $k$-powers and divisibility

Tags: nt.number-theory, elementary-proofs

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Determine integers, $n+1\leq r\leq 3n+2$, such that for all integers, $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$, $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_m$, satisfying the equations
$$
a_1b_1^k+a_2b_2^k+\cdots+a_mb_m^k=0
$$
for every $1\leq k \leq n$, the condition,
$$
r\mid a_1b_1^r+a_2b_2^r+\cdots+a_mb_m^r
$$
also holds.

Comment: Could you provide some more context? you're formulating the question as if it were an exercise (I'm not competent to detect whether it's indeed one)

Comment: $m$ has no relation to $n$, $r$, $k$?